# Chrome will ONLY request the HTTPS version of a website but there is not actually a secure version

Tags: google-chrome, https

I was curious if a website (which shall remain nameless) supported HTTPS so I added an S to the protocol of the URL ... now if I try and visit the HTTP version of the site in Chrome, it still tries to request the Secure (HTTPS) version of the site. Unfortunately the site isn't set up to use HTTPS so now the page is partially broken... how can I make Chrome switch back to the unsecure version of the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the Chrome Omnibox (Address bar) history using Shift + Del Key. Delete the browsing history from Chrome that should fix the problem. If you own the site, you can use a Apache .htaccess to force only http.

Answer (score 1):

If the domain you were visiting had an improperly configured hsts strict headers served from their https site, then you might need to clear the entry for that site.

In chrome you would need to visit this URL `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` which permits you to delete entries from.

Source: http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers